# How to reverse (mirror) a recursive binary search tree's subtrees

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a binary search tree in Java. My BST takes a number of "keywords" and inserts them into the tree using mostly recursive methods.

Unfortunately, it seems to be adding them backwards, E.x. the right side is higher letters (a-c...) than the left side (x-z...).

I cannot figure out how to correctly reverse the logic.

Here is my insertion code:

```
  /**
 * This method creates a new record for theFileData.
 * This is a recursive insertion method, that adds recordToAdd to the list of records
 * for the node associated with theKeyword.
 * 
 * If there is no keyword, create a new Node for it.
 * 
 * @param theKeyword keyword to associate with new record.
 * @param theFileData file data to associate with new record.
 */
public void insert(String theKeyword, FileData fd) {
    if (fd == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Invalid file data.");
    }
    if (theKeyword == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Invalid keyword.");
    }
    theKeyword = theKeyword.toLowerCase();

    Record recordToAdd = new Record(fd.id, fd.author, fd.title, null);

    // step one is to find the node with keyword theKeyword. That will give us the correct list to insert into.
    if (root == null) {
        /*
         * If the tree is currently empty, we create a new node as root.
         * This node than has the record added to it's records list.
         */
        Node newNode = new Node(theKeyword);
        newNode.update(recordToAdd);
        root = newNode;
    } else if (!contains(theKeyword)) {
        Node newNode = new Node(theKeyword);
        newNode.update(recordToAdd);
        insert(root, newNode);
    } else {
        Node target = find(theKeyword, root);
        target.update(recordToAdd);
    }
}

/**
 * This recursive insertion helper method allows us to quickly and easily add a new Node object
 * to our BST.
 */
private Node insert(Node theParent, Node theNode) {
    if (theParent == null) {
        return theNode;
    } else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) < 0) {
        theParent.right = insert(theParent.right, theNode);
    } else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) > 0) {
        theParent.left = insert(theParent.left, theNode);
    }
    return theParent;
}

/**
 * This helper method searches for a given keyword, returning the node when found.
 * 
 * @return Node containing the keyword you are looking for. Else null.
 */
private Node find(String keyword, Node root) {
    if (keyword == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid keyword.");
    }

    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
    if (keyword.compareTo(root.keyword) > 0) {
        return find(keyword, root.left);
    }
    if (keyword.compareTo(root.keyword) < 0) {
        return find(keyword, root.right);
    }
    return root;
}

/**
 * This method simply calls the find helper method. If find returns null, we know the value does not exist.
 * 
 * @param keyword keyword to search for.
 * @return true or false depending on if the keyword exists in the BST.
 */
public boolean contains(String keyword) {

    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();

    if (find(keyword, root) != null) {
        return true; // if the keyword exists.
    }
    return false;
}
```

**strong text**

Here is a graphic representation of the tree:

|   |   |-------blobs
|   |-------buildings
|   |   |   |-------causal-relationships
|   |   |   |   |-------classification-rules
|   |   |-------clustering
|-------content-based
|   |-------data-mining
database
|   |   |-------distance-measures
|   |   |   |-------image-display
|   |-------image-management
|-------image-retrieval
|   |   |   |-------image-stack
|   |   |   |   |   |-------indexing
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------information-retrieval
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-------instance-based
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------instance-based
|   |   |   |   |-------knowledge
|   |   |-------lines
|   |-------matching
|   |   |   |   |   |-------multimedia
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-------neural-networks
|   |   |   |   |-------pose
|   |   |   |-------pruning
|   |   |   |   |-------queries
|   |   |-------query-by-example
|   |   |   |   |-------query-trees
|   |   |   |-------recognition
|   |   |   |   |   |-------region-based
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-------relational
|   |   |   |   |-------search
|   |   |   |   |   |-------similarity
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------spatial
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------temporal
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------time-related
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-------triangle-inequality
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |-------weighting

Blobs should be on the left, matching should be on the right, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, reverse the < and >. so that the code reads

```
private Node insert(Node theParent, Node theNode) {
if (theParent == null) {
    return theNode;
} else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) > 0) {
    theParent.right = insert(theParent.right, theNode);
} else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) < 0) {
    theParent.left = insert(theParent.left, theNode);
}
    return theParent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to update my remove method to iterate in a similar manner. It was a simple mis-understanding of the compareTo() methods return values.

Answer (score 1):

In this method:

```
private Node insert(Node theParent, Node theNode) {
    if (theParent == null) {
        return theNode;
    } else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) < 0) {
        theParent.right = insert(theParent.right, theNode);
    } else if (theNode.keyword.compareTo(theParent.keyword) > 0) {
        theParent.left = insert(theParent.left, theNode);
    }
    return theParent;
}
```

When the node you want to insert is lexicographically less than the parent, you're inserting to the right. A word starting with `'a'` is lexicographically less than a word starting with `'z'`, so you are getting exactly what the code suggests you want.

To amend this, just flip the comparisons everywhere.